# xslt fast on Chrome, slow on IE

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, internet-explorer, xslt, tablesorter

I'm fairly new to XSLT, but I thought I understood it's basics thanks to a book and W3, but I've run into a problem I can't resolve... I have a large XML file (no option for a server-side method) with nearly 10k records.

Here's a sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
     <severeinjury>
        <record>
            <ID>1111111111</ID>
            <upa>1111111</upa>
            <eventDate>2015-01-01</eventDate>
            <employer>EMPLOYER</employer>
            <address>ADDRESS</address>
            <address2/>
            <city>CITY</city>
            <state>ST</state>
            <zip>12345</zip>
            <NAICS>1111111</NAICS>
            <Hospitalized>1</Hospitalized>
            <Amputation>0</Amputation>
            <inspectionNumber>111111</inspectionNumber>
            <finalNarrative>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.</finalNarrative>
            <nid>xxx</nid>
            <ntitle>Text</ntitle>
            <pid>xxx</pid>
            <ptitle>Text</ptitle>
            <eid>xxx</eid>
            <etitle>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text</etitle>
            <sid>xxxx</sid>
            <stitle>Text Text Text Text</stitle>
            <ssid>xxxx</ssid>
            <sstitle>Text Text Text Text Text</sstitle>
        </record>
        <--and so-forth for nearly 10k records -->
    </severeinjury>
```

The xsl uses `for-each` and `choose`, but is fairly vanilla:

```
<xsl:output method="html" />

<xsl:template match="severeinjury">
    <table class="table table-striped" id="severeInjuryTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-placeholder="ID">ID</th>
                <th data-placeholder="ID">UPA</th>
                <th data-placeholder="yyyy/mm/dd">Date</th>
                <th data-placeholder="Employer">Employer</th>
                <th data-placeholder="Address">Address</th>
                <th data-placeholder="City">City</th>
                <th class="filter-select" data-placeholder="Select State">ST</th>
                <th data-placeholder="Zip">Zip</th>
                <th data-placeholder="NAICS">Primary NAICS</th>
                <th  class="filter-select" data-placeholder="Select Result">Result</th>
                <th data-placeholder="Inspection#">Insp #</th>
                <th data-placeholder="Narrative">Final Narrative</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="12" class="ts-pager form-horizontal">
                    <button type="button" class="btn first" title="First Page"><i class="icon-step-backward glyphicon glyphicon-step-backward"></i></button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn prev" title="Previous Page"><i class="icon-arrow-left glyphicon glyphicon-backward"></i></button>
                    <span class="pagedisplay"></span> <!-- this can be any element, including an input -->
                    <button type="button" class="btn next" title="Next Page"><i class="icon-arrow-right glyphicon glyphicon-forward"></i></button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn last" title="Last Page"><i class="icon-step-forward glyphicon glyphicon-step-forward"></i></button>
                    <select class="pagesize input-mini" title="Select page size">
                        <option selected="selected" value="10">10</option>
                        <option value="25">25</option>
                        <option value="50">50</option>
                        <option value="75">75</option>
                        <option value="100">100</option>
                    </select>
                    <select class="pagenum input-mini" title="Select page number"></select>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
        <xsl:for-each select="record">
        <xsl:sort select="eventdate" />
            <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="ID" /></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="upa" /></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="eventDate" /></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="employer" /></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="address" /> <xsl:value-of select="address2" /></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="city" /></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="state" /></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="zip" /></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="NAICS" /></td>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="Hospitalized = 1">
                        <td>Hospitalized</td>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="Amputation = 1">
                        <td>Amputation</td>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="Hospitalized = 0">
                        <td>Amputation</td>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="Amputation = 0">
                        <td>Hospitalized</td>
                    </xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>
                <td>
                    <a title="View the inspection details for this case" href="{inspectionNumber}" target="_blank">
                        <xsl:value-of select="inspectionNumber" />
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="finalNarrative" /> 
                    <div class="mocktable">
                        <div class="mockrow">
                            <div class="mockcell center"><xsl:value-of select="nid" /></div>
                            <div class="mockcell center"><xsl:value-of select="pid" /></div>
                            <div class="mockcell center"><xsl:value-of select="eid" /></div>
                            <div class="mockcell center"><xsl:value-of select="sid" /><xsl:text> </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="ssid" /></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="mockrow">
                            <div class="mockcell"><xsl:value-of select="ntitle" /></div>
                            <div class="mockcell"><xsl:value-of select="ptitle" /></div>
                            <div class="mockcell"><xsl:value-of select="etitle" /></div>
                            <div class="mockcell"><xsl:value-of select="stitle" /><xsl:text> </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="sstitle" /></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And finally, the javascript (with tablesorter.js thrown in):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var resultTables = $('#severeinjury');
    resultTables.html('<p><img src="images/spinner.gif" alt="" /> Loading...</p>');
    displayResult();

    function loadXMLDoc(dname) {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
        try {xhttp.responseType = 'msxml-document'} catch(e){}
        xhttp.send("");
        return xhttp.responseXML;
    }

    function displayResult() {
        xml = loadXMLDoc("./xml/severeinjury.xml");
        xsl = loadXMLDoc("./xml/severeinjury.xsl");

        if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createHTMLDocument && typeof XSLTProcessor != 'undefined') {
            // code for Chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc.
            xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
            xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
            resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml,document);
            resultTables.html(resultDocument);

        } else if (window.ActiveXObject || xhttp.responseType == 'msxml-document'){
            // code for IE
            ex = xml.transformNode(xsl);
            document.getElementById('severeinjury').innerHTML = ex;
        }
    }

    $('#severeInjuryTable').tablesorter({
        theme : "bootstrap",
        sortList : [[2,0]],
        widthFixed: true,
        headerTemplate : '{content} {icon}',
        widgets : [ "uitheme", "filter", "zebra" ],
        widgetOptions : {zebra : ["even", "odd"],
            filter_external : '.search',
            filter_saveFilters : true,
            filter_reset : '.reset',
            filter_hideFilters : false,
            filter_cssFilter : 'tablesorter-filter'
        }
    }).tablesorterPager({container: $('.ts-pager'),cssGoto  : ".pagenum",removeRows: false,output: '{startRow} - {endRow} / {filteredRows} ({totalRows})'});    
});
```

This takes 30 seconds to load the entire table and apply tablesorter on Chrome and Firefox. It takes 10 minutes to load in IE. I suspect it's IE's method for xml transform that's causing the slowdown.

I need this to be a lot faster on IE (especially considering everyone I have to show this to for approval is stuck with only IE as their browser). But I'm spinning my wheels trying to find the right solution. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I would first try to create a static document using the XSLT and then check if the performance difference is also present when you apply that tablesorter on the static HTML. I don't see how there is much you can improve if the XSLT is a simple as that.

Comment: It's not tablesorter. It's the size of the xml, I think, and how the browser handles building it. I tried it out with the xml reduced to 20, 1k, and 5k records. 20 records loaded almost instantly in both browser types (Chrome and IE). 1k lagged just a bit slower, about 10 seconds, in IE and 5k loaded in about 5 minutes in IE compared to 15 seconds in Chrome. I suspect it has to do with the number of records and the for-each loop. I think xsltProcessor handles the loop differently than IE's transformNode.

Comment: Which IE version is that, have you tried to profile the code and check whether it is the `transformNode` call or the `innerHTML` parsing that performs bad?

Comment: IE 11. I've emulated in 10 and seen *some* improvement in speed, but not enough to write home about. I haven't emulated 9 yet, because I keep having to wait 10 minutes for the page to render.

Comment: @MartinHonnen: It's definitely the transformNode. I updated my parser to `resultTables.html(ex);` (which is the same call I use for the standard browsers) and it's still a 10 minute job.

Comment: Can you live with doing the XSLT directly in an HTML iframe where you load the XSLT directly with `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="./xml/severeinjury.xsl"?>` inside the XML document? Perhaps IE that way performs better than doing XSLT called from Javascript. As for the XSLT, the only "complex" stuff in there is the sorting, so you could try to remove that to measure whether it is the operation that takes so much time. If IE really needs that much time I am not sure how to reduce it other than breaking up the XML and loading only parts of it.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem and generated a sample with 10000 records, then wrote the most straightforward, IE specific code using MSXML to perform the transformation, the HTML document is at http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/test201607070501.html, IE 11 on Windows 10 seems to handle that fine, I think it takes less than a minute to display the document.

Comment: In http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/test201607070502.html I have used `console.time()/console.timeEnd()` and IE 11 gives me the following data `Transformation: 526,934ms` and `Rendering: 2.893,008ms`. So at least for that sample the `innerHTML` parsing of the transformation result takes five times compared to the loading of the both documents and the transformation.

Comment: @MartinHonnen This is turning into a chat, but it's a good discussion... your samples are a bit slower in IE for me, but IS has that browser really locked down. I imagine it will be even slower for the decision makers as I have "special permission" for less draconian settings... It seems that tablesorter, specifically the pager function, is the culprit. When I take TS out of the script, I render in 3 minutes in IE. When I put it back in but leave out the pager, it's still 3 minutes. Oh, and it's still 30 seconds in Chrome.

Comment: Some of the browser locking is caused by the synchronous loading, so switching to asynchronous loading as tried in http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/test201607070503.html might make the browser appear more responsive. As for the paging and table sorting problems, I can't help with that, maybe if you retag your question as JQuery or whatever framework that is someone can help tuning that.